# May I move a hex number in Catan Europe if there is a robber on that hex?

Tags: catan

In Catan Europe Board Game there are some hexes without a number. When we come there, we get a number from an already taken hex and place that number on a new hex.

So, my question is:
May I move a hex number in Catan Europe from the old hex to a new one if there is a robber on that old hex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you can.**

While there is no rule specifically stating this, [the rules](https://www.catan.com/sites/default/files/2021-08/catan_moe_rules_090612s.pdf) simply don't say or imply any sort of restriction that would make the robber relevant here:

> Place and move a number token: If a newly built trading post
> is adjacent to a terrain hex without number in the center of the
> hex, choose one of the face-down number tokens from the supply
> and place it on the token space of that terrain hex. The number
> token must have the same color as the hex’s token space. If there
> are no more face-down number tokens of matching color in the
> supply, you must move a number token has already been placed.
> **Remove any number token of matching color from another
> terrain hex** and place it on the empty token space of your new
> terrain hex.

Comment: Technically, the rules (or, at least, the basic rules) do say "If you roll a “7,” ... You must move the robber Y immediately to the number token of any other terrain hex or to the desert Y hex." Thus, moving the number token requires moving the robber (because the robber is on top of the number token, so at the very least you have to move the robber to another part of the hex).